# Basic database (MongoDB) performance question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, database

I'm building a web app for bookmark storage with a directory system.
I've already got these collections set up:

- Path(s)
  ---> Directories (embedded documents)
  ---> Links (embedded documents)
- User(s)

So performance wise, should I:
- add the user id to the created path
- embed the whole Paths collection into the specific user

I want to pick option 2, but yeah, I dunno...

EDIT:
I was also thinking about making the whole interface ajaxified. So, that means I'll load the directories and links from a specific path (from the logged in user) through ajax. That way, it's faster and I don't have to touch the user collection. Maybe that changes things?

Like I've said in the comments, 1 huge collection in the whole database seems kinda strange. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the main purpose of the mongoDB is to support redundant data.I will recommend **second** option is better because In your scenario what I feel that if you embed path collection into the specific user then by using only single query you can get all data about user as well as related to path collection as well.

And if you follow first option then you have to fire two separates queries to get all data which will increase your work somewhat.

As mongodb brings data into the RAM so after getting data from one collection you can store it into cursor and from that cursor data you can fetch data from another collection. So if we see performance wise I dont think it will affect a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems kinda strange tho', to have only one huge collection in the database. Isn't it? Oh, and there's something else.. I'll edit the question...

Comment: @Icid Logically your database can grow up to any size depending on your storage size so dont worry about that and on huge collections if you perform indexing then you will get results more faster.If you want to do indexing then use solr like stuff because mongodb also providing indexing but that will suddenly increase operation load on your db. If still you have doubt in second approach then you can go with first approach and make second query on cursor which was earlier explain by me.

Answer (score 1):

RE: the edit. If you are going to store everything in a single doc and use embedded docs, then when you make your queries make sure you just select the data you need, otherwise you will load the whole doc including the embedded docs.

Comment: Like this? current_user.paths.where( :location => '/directory' ).first

Comment: Depends on your OM, With mongoid e.g. current_user.paths.where( :location => '/directory' ).only(:id, :name)